# Front end Angularjs + backend Jersey REST Services + need to set development environment

Tags: angularjs, tomcat, jersey

I am a beginner with Angularjs. I have my project configured in eclipse where Front end is Angularjs and backend is Jersey services. I am using the Tomcat application servers. The problem here is that every time I change the html or js code, I need to re-deploy the application on Tomcat. It's wasting a lot of time. Do you know what should be the correct approach in the development environment? Basically I don't want to re-deploy the application for the minor front end changes during the development.

Comment: If you're using Tomcat, you should have a folder in your program files where it's being deployed to. C: -> Program Files -> Apache Software Foundation -> Tomcat 8.0 -> ... You can just copy your friend end files to that when there isn't a backend change paired with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [node.js](https://nodejs.org/) npm build function,

no its not only a language (people think that it is a language). but its like a framework  I/O model for building application in runtime it is used in developement environment to save time.. also it have many  utilities. ;)